# Hiding textView underbar while typing

Tags: android, textview

I want to hide the underbar of textView in android . How can i achieve this .I have already tried setting the background color to 'transparent' or 'null'.But during typing underbar is still visible.

Comment: Did you mean the `EditText` or `AutoCompleteTextView` ? because the  `TextView` does not have an underlying bar !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <EditText
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:hint="@string/hello"

 android:background="#00000000" />
```

UPDATE :

try this

someTextView.clearComposingText();

hope it helps

Comment: already tried this .. what you told will just remove the underbar when one has not given the text in the editText .. once you start giving input underbar again gets visible . But thanks for replying :)